# understanding XMLGregorianCalendar/GregorianCalendar time in milliseconds

Tags: java, xml, utc, timezone-offset

I am trying to understand, the `getTimeInMillis()` method of `GregorianCalendar` object in Java.

Consider the code snippet below

```
        XMLGregorianCalendar cal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2014-01-19T00:00:00.000-00:00");
        XMLGregorianCalendar cal1 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2014-01-19T00:00:00.000+04:30");
        System.out.println(cal.toGregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis());
        System.out.println(cal1.toGregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis());
```

The output is as follows

```
1390089600000
1390073400000
```

This is where my confusion arises. if you see the input times, `2014-01-19T00:00:00.000-00:00` and `2014-01-19T00:00:00.000+04:30`, they refer to the same instant of time. So the UTC time for them which is supposed to be returned by `getTimeInMillis()` should be same, but you see there is a difference. The difference in this case is 4.5 hours expressed in milliseconds, which is the timezone offset in the second time string.

Not sure where my understanding is going wrong.

Comment: How are the input times the same? What am I missing?

Comment: Your statement "they refer to the same instance" is confusing, because you have two distinct instances: cal and cal1.

Comment: changed it to indicate what I meant, "same instant of time". Midnight at GMT and 4.30 am in the timezone which is 4.30 hours ahead of GMT are the same instant of time, or at least this is my understanding...

Comment: @chimanrao You have the same *local times*, not the same instant (see your input part before the offset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the offset is +00:00 then it it UTC time.

If the offset is different, for example +04:30, then you have to subtract this offset from local time (left part before offset part) in order to get UTC time.

Finally with same local times but different offsets you get different UTC times! The general formula is:

```
UTC + offset = (local time)
```